# Using Title in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, dart-pub

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'The Recipes For The Category!',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got error with this code and the error in title: Text(categoryTitle),what should i do to fix it?

Comment: can you please share what error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to string

```
Text(categoryTitle.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because the type of `categoryTitle` might not be in **String** format. You can solve it by follwing ways:

1. You can convert `categoryTitle` to **String** when you are first assigning like this:

`final String categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'].toString();`

2. You can convert to String when you want to display in Widgets in the UI like this:

```js
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle.toString()),
      ),
```

However, I would suggest to convert to the type you need while assigning it only so that you don't have to worry about type conversion later on.